# JavaScript code wont work in Shopify... Help :(

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am trying to add another announcement bar at our Shopify store below the current announcement bar so that we have 2 stacked on each other but my Javascript wont work. :(

I even followed these guidelines to make sure everything was correct.
Link:https://www.askquesty.com/post/how-to-add-javascript-shopify-tutorial
Can anyone help me out?

My code:

```
<script>
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

var el = document.createElement("span.l");
el.innerHTML = "<p class=announcementBar2>FREE SHIPPING</p>";
var div = document.getElementById("announcement-bar");
insertAfter(div, el);
</script>
```

Comment: `document.createElement("span.l")` creates a `<span.l>` element. Next you're putting a <p> inside a <span>, which is also invalid. However the code "works", in the sense that the text appears in the document: https://jsfiddle.net/d7oftjsg/ Are you getting any error messages in the browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this might work, I wouldn't recommend using JavaScript for this since it may cause layout shifts. I would modify the announcement bar snippet instead, can you provide the GitHub repo with your theme?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using HTML in the header.liquid

```
<div class="promobar-content">

  <div class="bar-inner">
    <span class="header-promotion-text header-promotion-text--desktop">
      <p>FREE SHIPPING with 2 bags</p>
    </span>
  </div>

</div>
```